# Some files are accessible from the outside in a private bitbucket repo

Tags: bitbucket

I have a private repo in bitbucket for a report i have to write in latex. The automatically created  pdf (by pdftex using texlipse) unfortunately is accessable from the outside, but the source files (*.tex) are not.
How can i prevent other users from accessing it (although it is a really cryptic url).
Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: Sounds like perhaps a bug and should be reported to Atlassian.

Comment: Done. i will update this post as soon as i have any news.

Comment: For everyone, who might be interested:
[support ticket](https://support.atlassian.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/11/BBS-13350)